# Video rendering issue on mobile chrome when using object-fit

Tags: android, css, html5-video, mobile-chrome

I've found a strange behaviour while programming an interactive video special.

Mobile chrome shows an odd border below the video. It is related to the default `object-fit: contain` rule that is set by chrome. If explicitly set to `object-fit: none` the border disappears.

In my case, i have to/want to use `object-fit: cover` and this has the same glitch.

[Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vQof.jpg)

It looks like this behaviour came with one of the latest chrome/android updates. On another device with Android 9 it looks normal. Can anyone reproduce this issue?

My versions are:

Chrome 77.0.3865.92

Android 10; Pixel 3a Build/QP1A. 190711.020.C3

```html
<video loop autoplay muted playsinline src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I cannot reproducte since the "Run code snippet"-button does not appear on my mobile device. But you already provided a solution so what's your question? Are you really just asking if one can reproducte that?

Comment: My problem is, that I have to use object-fit, in my case object-fit: cover, but it doesn't work currently. In addition, maybe there is someone else with this problem and is looking for an workaround.